# undefined return ajax success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

here is my simple code in trying to get data from php to ajax.
i just wanted to get a simple data pass back to ajax success. i already searched for this but i cant get it properly. my code is really simple.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#1").click(function(){
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: { "txt": "try"},
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {                    
                 alert(html.mes);
            }
            }); 
});
});
</SCRIPT>
<pre><button id="1">try</button></pre>
```

Then i load a ajax.php that has a simple code too

```
$var['mes'] = 'message';
echo json_encode($var);
```

and its alerting me "undefined". i know this is simple but i cant find it out where do am i wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell jQuery that the script is running JSON:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#1").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: { "txt": "try"},
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {                    
                alert(html.mes);
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you. thats the only problem i have sorry for this. thanks a lot sir